The doubt about the redirection of some stdout within its transitional period
How to keep the complete stdout with its transitional period output ？
As the following typical example, you can see that the yum metadata refreshing status would not be redirected to its yr.log. 
So my question is how to retain these outputs during its transitional period .

# 
# yum  -v repolist
Not loading "rhnplugin" plugin, as it is disabled
Not loading "product-id" plugin, as it is disabled
Loading "refresh-packagekit" plugin
Loading "security" plugin
Not loading "subscription-manager" plugin, as it is disabled
Config time: 0.015
Yum Version: 3.2.29
RHEL_6.4_x86-64                                    | 3.9 kB     00:00 ... 
RHEL_6.4_zlocal                                    | 2.9 kB     00:00 ... 
Setting up Package Sacks
pkgsack time: 0.012
Repo-id      : RHEL_6.4_x86-64
Repo-name    : RHEL_6.4_x86-64_dvd_all
Repo-revision: 1359576928
Repo-updated : Thu Jan 31 04:22:56 2013
Repo-pkgs    : 3,648
Repo-size    : 3.2 G
Repo-baseurl : file:///mnt/
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Wed Jun 26 08:26:11 2024)

Repo-id      : RHEL_6.4_zlocal
Repo-name    : RHEL_6.4_x86-64_dvd_zlocal
Repo-revision: 1715738735
Repo-updated : Wed Mar 31 17:26:56 2021
Repo-pkgs    : 3,720
Repo-size    : 3.2 G
Repo-baseurl : file:///install/rhel_6.4_x86_64/
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Wed Jun 26 08:26:11 2024)

repolist: 7,368
# 
# 
# 
# yum -v repolist 1> /tmp/yr.log 2> /tmp/yr.err
# 
# 
# cat /tmp/yr.log
Not loading "rhnplugin" plugin, as it is disabled
Not loading "product-id" plugin, as it is disabled
Loading "refresh-packagekit" plugin
Loading "security" plugin
Not loading "subscription-manager" plugin, as it is disabled
Config time: 0.069
Yum Version: 3.2.29
Setting up Package Sacks
pkgsack time: 0.712
Repo-id      : RHEL_6.4_x86-64
Repo-name    : RHEL_6.4_x86-64_dvd_all
Repo-revision: 1359576928
Repo-updated : Thu Jan 31 04:22:56 2013
Repo-pkgs    : 3,648
Repo-size    : 3.2 G
Repo-baseurl : file:///mnt/
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Wed Jun 26 15:24:26 2024)

Repo-id      : RHEL_6.4_zlocal
Repo-name    : RHEL_6.4_x86-64_dvd_zlocal
Repo-revision: 1715738735
Repo-updated : Wed May 15 10:06:56 2024
Repo-pkgs    : 3,720
Repo-size    : 3.2 G
Repo-baseurl : file:///install/rhel_6.4_x86_64/
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Wed Jun 26 15:24:27 2024)

repolist: 7,368
# 


Either something gets to yr.err, or (more likely) the tool detects the relevant file is not a tty and adjusts its behavior. See How to trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal.

I'm not entirely sure what I should be seeing in the output. The two sections look the same to me.

@Kusalananda It's probably about RHEL_6.4_x86-64                                    | 3.9 kB     00:00 ... and the next line. They look like progress meters, most likely they have been updated many times using escape sequences.

Yes,  I also think it does keep up with the progress meter ......

Using the script -q -c function to capture the progress meter log.
# 
#  
# script -q /tmp/yvr_1.out -c 'yum -v repolist' 1> /tmp/yvr_1.log 2> /tmp/yvr_1.err
# 
# 
# cat /tmp/yvr_1.log
Not loading "katello" plugin, as it is disabled
Not loading "product-id" plugin, as it is disabled
Not loading "rhnplugin" plugin, as it is disabled
Loading "security" plugin
Not loading "subscription-manager" plugin, as it is disabled
Loading "verify" plugin
Config time: 0.071
Yum Version: 3.2.22
Cluster                                                   | 1.5 kB     00:00     
ClusterStorage                                            | 1.5 kB     00:00     
RHEL_5.8_local                                            |  951 B     00:00     
Server                                                    | 1.5 kB     00:00     
VT                                                        | 1.3 kB     00:00     
Setting up Package Sacks
pkgsack time: 0.023
Repo-id      : Cluster
Repo-name    : Cluster_r58
Repo-updated : Fri Feb  3 02:38:19 2012
Repo-pkgs    : 32
Repo-size    : 83 M
Repo-baseurl : file:///mnt/Cluster/
Repo-expire  : 3,600 second(s) (last: Mon Jul 15 16:33:35 2024)

Repo-id      : ClusterStorage
Repo-name    : ClusterStorage_r58
Repo-updated : Fri Feb  3 02:39:28 2012
Repo-pkgs    : 39
Repo-size    : 11 M
Repo-baseurl : file:///mnt/ClusterStorage/
Repo-expire  : 3,600 second(s) (last: Mon Jul 15 16:33:35 2024)

Repo-id      : RHEL_5.8_local
Repo-name    : RHEL_5.8_x86-64_all_local
Repo-updated : Tue Apr 23 10:43:03 2024
Repo-pkgs    : 3,414
Repo-size    : 3.6 G
Repo-baseurl : file:///install/rhel_5.8_x86-64_local/
Repo-expire  : 3,600 second(s) (last: Mon Jul 15 16:33:35 2024)

Repo-id      : Server
Repo-name    : Server_r58
Repo-updated : Fri Feb  3 02:39:04 2012
Repo-pkgs    : 3,285
Repo-size    : 3.3 G
Repo-baseurl : file:///mnt/Server/
Repo-expire  : 3,600 second(s) (last: Mon Jul 15 16:33:35 2024)

Repo-id      : VT
Repo-name    : VT_r58
Repo-updated : Fri Feb  3 02:38:17 2012
Repo-pkgs    : 58
Repo-size    : 193 M
Repo-baseurl : file:///mnt/VT/
Repo-expire  : 3,600 second(s) (last: Mon Jul 15 15:33:36 2024)

repolist: 6,828
# 
# 

